# Cannot resolve symbol R.menu and R.id.menu_settings

Tags: android

I have been struggling for this problem for few hours already but I still can't manage to solve this problem. Hope someone can help me to figure it out what is happening to my code.

Android Studio can't resolve the symbol **menu** and **action_settings** in my code. I tried to clean and rebuild and invalidate cache / restart for many times but it does not help to solve my problem.

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(**R.menu.menu_main**, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == **R.id.action_settings**) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is there any problem to my code? So sorry that I'm still new to android studio, hope you guys can forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a menu xml file in with folder as menu under res. In the new Android Studio Activities it does not create the menu folder neither it creates the menus for the activities.

After adding the menu folder, you need to manually add the menu_main.xml file. After that, you may use this code below to access the menu.

**Java:**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                Intent intent_logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_logout);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was because i used switch()... when i use if/else if instead it works perfectly, that why i think the first answer will not work.
Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    {
}
```